# How to know if the build has been done without failure

Tags: java, swing, apache-commons

i'm newbie to java and i'm trying to build a simple mail client using apache commons mail library,
everything works fine, but i would like to get JPaneOption or any other window to notify me if the mail has been sent or failed.

here is the code am using :

```
package test;

import import org.apache.commons.mail.*;
   public class Mailer{
   public static void main(String[] args){

    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator("username", "password");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
    email.send();
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Wrap the send in a try/catch block, catching EmailException. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#send(). Given that it is a checked exception, I am surprised that you aren't having to handle this already.

Comment: So, having a look at the JavaDocs, [`EMail#send`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#send()) *"returns the message id of the underlying MimeMessage*" or throws *"`EmailException` - the sending failed"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follow

```
package test;

import import org.apache.commons.mail.*;
   public class Mailer{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator("username", "password");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
    email.send();
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Email sent succeefully");
}catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
    e.getMessage(),
    "Error",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please mark answer as "right".

Comment: Done... thanks again anant

Answer (score 0):

```
String message;
try {
    email.send();
    message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Success");
    resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  ex.getMessage());
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```